# Pandas DataFrame DateTimes vs Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, types

I have a DataFrame with a single `day` column:

```
|     | day                       |
|----:|:--------------------------|
|   0 | 2021-08-28 00:00:00+00:00 |
|   1 | 2021-08-28 02:00:00+00:00 |
|   2 | 2021-08-28 04:00:00+00:00 |
| ... |                       ... |
|   n | 2021-08-28 16:00:00+00:00 |

>>> df.dtypes
day    datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtype: object
```

I noticed pandas returns different date data-types when sampling and indexing and have to be converted to be compared.

#### Index Query

```
>>> df.day[0]
Timestamp('2021-08-28 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')

>>> type(df.day[0])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

#### Sample Query

```
>>> df.day.sample(1).values[0]
numpy.datetime64('2021-09-04T12:00:00.000000000')

>>> type(df.day.sample(1).values[0])
numpy.datetime64
```

What's going on? Why does pandas use different data-types in the two scenarios?

- Python: 3.8.10
- Pandas: 1.2.5

Comment: As you can see in official docs values would return everything in numpy flavour :) __ Return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame. __

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas stores datetimes as numpy's underlying `datetime64` type. The reason (as opposed to storing as a `Timestamp`, which is a `datetime.datetime` subclass) is simple - performance.  When retrieving a particular value though, it returns a `Timestamp` object, which is more convenient to work with since it support all `datetime.datetime` methods.